# How can I determine the gap of more than 3 days between dates using Lag to obtain previous row's date?

Tags: json, sql-server

I recently wrote the post:

[How can I correctly translate this complicated JSON into a SQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59067801/how-can-i-correctly-translate-this-complicated-json-into-a-sql-table/59068804#59068804)

and in it, I needed to grab some JSON that had numerous sub elements. I have now figured this out, but one of the problems I have next is how to determine the people identified as having had a gap (ideally of 3 days or more). The field in question is DateDone, and you may see from this previous post that there will be some days where it goes 01, 02, 02, 02, 05, 06/10/2019.

I have the current code, based on what I've learnt of this issue:

```
Select *, GapDays = Coalesce(DateDiff(Day,lag(DateDone) over(partition by ServiceUserName order by DateDone), DateDone)-1, 0)
    from [JSONBMs-Home Name]
```

but it products the following data, which after one count of 02, 02, 02 etc the GapDays will = 0, -1, -1 -1. I want it to show as 02, 02, 02 = 0, and then 05/10/2019 = 3, and 06/10/2019 = 1.

[image]

How do I do this? I feel I'm very close. The goal then to subquery this to show the resident's name and the date ranges of the various gaps of more than 3 days.

Thanks in advance.

Ant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isnull the Nullif of -1, to 0:

```
SELECT *,
 ISNULL(NULLIF(
      DATEDIFF(Day, LAG(DateDone) OVER (PARTITION BY ServiceUserName ORDER BY DateDone), DateDone)-1
      ,-1), 0) AS GapDays
FROM [JSONBMs-Home Name]
ORDER BY DateDone;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/PFB46699)

And to limit on the calculated `GapDays`, wrap it in a sub-query.
For `GapDays>0` the ISNULL/NULLIF hack isn't really required.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
     DATEDIFF(Day, LAG(DateDone) OVER (PARTITION BY ServiceUserName ORDER BY DateDone), DateDone)-1 AS GapDays
    FROM [JSONBMs-Home Name]
) q
WHERE GapDays > 0
ORDER BY DateDone;
```

Comment: Fabulous. Thank you very much. That does seem to work via RT. I’ll try it with my code tonight to confirm but I’m sure it will work there, too. My background is more Delphi based, but I’m trying to do as much of the data processing through SQL if I can, and I’m learning all the time. Thanks again!

Comment: Is there a way to use this GapDays to filter the query to e.g. where GapDays >= 4? I realise there seems to be no real way to use windowed items in where clauses, but another way?

Comment: @Ant  Sadly Microsoft only allows the window functions in the `SELECT` and the `ORDER BY`.  I'd wish they would just add something like TeraData's `QUALIFY` already.  But you can wrap  that query in a sub-query, or a CTE.  Then use that criteria in the outer-query.   F.e. `select * from (<query with lag>) q where GapDays >= 4;`

Comment: Thanks. I've done this in the end. select *, GapDays from
(
 select *, IsNull(NullIf(DateDiff(Day,Lag(DateDone) over (partition by ServiceUserName order by DateDone), DateDone)-1,-1),0) as GapDays
 from [JSONBMs-Home Name]

) as SubQueryAlias
where GapDays > 4

Comment: @Ant Cool. Btw, why the 2 `GapsDays` in the result? And didn't you want `GapsDays >= 4`?

Comment: @Ant Btw, if you want to golf-code it, the isnull & nullif aren't actually needed if the result only needs to show GapsDays>0. ;)  Not that it would make a difference.  So just ignore that, it's just the ramblings of a [golfcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42827/lukstorms) :p

Comment: Haha. I confess to having to look that term up, but it makes sense now I know. Yes you're right, but I'll leave it in anyway for now. Thanks for all your help.